# Maps at a fundamental level, "this const expression has type "const char*" instead of the required "unsigned int" type

Tags: c++, visual-studio, maps

So I've been googling for a decent while, a search here turned up nothing so sure hope this isn't a duplicate

I was having some problems with assigning values to strings in a map but found a much more interesting problem, in that I can literally copy paste the example found on C++ Reference for map::map and it still comes up with the same error in the intellisense error report thing in Visual Studio. Found below:

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>

std::map<char,int> first;

first['a']=10;
first['b']=30;
first['c']=50;
first['d']=70;
```

This was in a header file loaded by the main .cpp so it's not in a function, I also copy pasted fncomp and classcomp on the offchance that it was an inbuilt function that got overridden (I was definitely out of ideas by this point) and unsurprisingly that wasn't it

Is my version of Visual Studio broken or something? I can't see what I could have possibly missed.

Comment: Are you saying [this program](http://ideone.com/OXeEKg) gave you the error in the title?

Comment: Those statements in which you access the map have no meaning outside a function.

Comment: I don't see any strings here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error message makes no sense whatsoever, but that's probably only because you're confusing the heck out of your IDE by writing these expression statements in random empty space.

Assignments must go in a *function*.

Only declarations can live at namespace scope.

Comment: My Visual Studio, for the given code, gives errors (both compiler ones and Intellisense's) that are much more intelligible than the one reported by the OP. Probably because it's not the real code.